# как вывести разные блоки div в зависимости от того авторизован пользователь или нет?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть сайт с блочной версткой. Блоки: header, navigation, content, menu, footer. Есть панелька навигации с кнопками(navigation). При нажатии на кнопки информация загружается в блок content.

Как сделать так, чтобы после авторизации на сайте, кнопка Войти, менялась на кнопку Выйти. Доступен только jacascript, который я не знаю.

Как я думаю, надо средством js проверять не истекли ли куки у пользователя, и если нет выводить блок navigation (Главная, аккаунт, о сайте, Выход), а если истекли, то выводить блок navigation2 (Главная, аккаунт, о сайте, Вход).

блоки задаю как:

```
<div id="navigation" style="display:none">
<div id="navigation1" style="display:none">
```

css:

```
#navigation {
display: block;
background: #a2a2a2;
width: 900px;
height: 40px;
}

#navigation1 {
display: block;
background: #a2a2a2;
width: 900px;
height: 40px;
}
```

js:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookie = " " + document.cookie;
    var search = " " + name + "=";
    var setStr = null;
    var offset = 0;
    var end = 0;
    if (cookie.length > 0) {
        offset = cookie.indexOf(search);
        if (offset != -1) {
            offset += search.length;
            end = cookie.indexOf(";", offset)
            if (end == -1) {
                end = cookie.length;
            }
            setStr = unescape(cookie.substring(offset, end));
        }
    }
    return(setStr);
}

myVar = getCookie("la2user");
if (myVar !== null)
  {document.getElementById('navigation1').style.display = 'block';  }
else
  {document.getElementById('navigation').style.display = 'block';  }
```

Пробую так. Не работает, хотя если после if писать `{alert(myVar)}` то куки выводит.

Comment: *Как я думаю, надо средством js проверять не истекли ли куки у пользователя* ну так проверяйте если у вас на сайте именно такая система авторизации. Все зависит от того как она реализована (эта система). Если он есть в куках - почитайте как работать с куками и сделайте, если чтото из того будет не выходить или не работать -  выложите тут, тут уже помогут.

Comment: система авторизации у меня другая. средствами cgi, вернее python выставляю куки, если выполняются все проверки.

Comment: Об авторизованности знает только сервер. И клиенту сообщать он не обязан. Если сообщает, то укажите в вопросе, как он это делает.

Answer (score 1):

Во первых вопрос, вам так и нужно чтобы один блок был в другом?

```
<div id="navigation" style="display:none">
<div id="navigation1" style="display:none">
```

Если нет тогда закройте теги -

```
<div id="navigation" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="navigation1" style="display:none"></div>
```

Тогда проблем не будет. У вас просто сейчас второй блок в первом, и если первый скрыт - то и второй будет скрыт не зависимо от свойств.

Comment: они закрыты. просто я опустил блоки где меню и закрывается.

`<div id="navigation" style="display:none">

    <a href="http://мойсайт.ru" class="button" style="display:none">ГЛАВНАЯ</a>`
...
</div>

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gpLk99w8/ если закрыты тогда все работает как и должно. А вообще лучше сразу генерировать *html* страницу в зависимости от того прошла авторизация или нет, с нужным вам блоком.

Comment: закрыты, но не работает. такое ощущение, что 
`{document.getElementById('navigation1').style.display = 'block';  }`
просто не выполняется

Comment: к тому коду что у вас приведен в вопросе я написал - закрыть теги и все работает, вон на фидл есть пример. В том примере можете поменять не равно на равно в условии, и увидите что покажет другой блок. Приведите тогда ваш конкретный код в котором хотите чтобы менялось.

Comment: да. посмотрел фидл.. там работает. у меня же просто меню исчезает. озадачен.. сейчас еще попробую всё в фидл загрузить

Comment: обратил внимание, что под footer появляется просто белый блок без надписей... это видимо и есть navigation, только как он туда смещается и почему без надписей. если пробую ставить сразу style='display:block' то нормально отображается..

Comment: без линка на ваш сайт или кода тут никто ничего больше не скажет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34489/discussion-between-moonvvell-and-sergey-white).